Stability Criterion for the vector form of a First Order One-Way Wave Equation
The scalar form of the hyperbolic PDE defining the homogeneous first order one-way wave equation is
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+a\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0$$
The (explicit) Lax-Friedrichs finite difference approximation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax%E2%80%93Friedrichs_method) with a time step $\Delta t$ and a spatial step $\Delta x$ can be shown from a Fourier-Von Neumann analysis to have the stability criterion
$$\Big|a \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x} \Big|\le 1$$
In the problem that I'm tackling, I have the vector form of the non-homogeneous First Order Wave Equation
$$\frac{\partial {\bf \overrightarrow u}}{\partial t}+{\bf \underline A}\frac{\partial {\bf \overrightarrow u}}{\partial x}={\bf\overrightarrow b}$$
where ${\bf \underline A}$ is non-sparse.
My question is - how would I express the stability criterion above for the vector form?
(I don't imagine that the non-homogeneous term ${\bf\overrightarrow b}$ has any impact on the stability criterion, but I've included it for formality)
Thanks
P.S: If as I had conjectured, the stability criterion is indeed
$$ \Delta t \le \frac{\Delta x}{\Big|\bf \underline A\Big|}$$
then this is terrible news for me, as the determinant is very large (of the order $10^{10}$) in normalised units.

The determinant likely has nothing to do with stability. It is more likely that the norm or the magnitude of the largest eigenvalue of $A$ will determine stability.

Thanks!! I had started to suspect as much (in fact in the limit of 1 dimension the only eigenvalue is $a$). I'm struggling a bit with how to prove this thoug,h by extending the F-vN approach to a multi-dimensional scenario.

Leveque - Numerical Methods for Conservation Laws (1992) Section 10.6 should answer your question

Thanks, @HyperbolicPDEfriend PDE ! Indeed it does! and in fact specifically confirms what whpowell96 had suggested above.

It's also great news for me as I can now use MUCH more reasonable time steps in my application!

Very nice to hear!

@HyperbolicPDEfriend, I'd appreciate it if you could take a look at my follow-up post at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4922001/solving-a-first-order-hyperbolic-system-of-pdes-with-an-ill-conditioned-matrix and let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks a ton again.
