Solving a First Order Hyperbolic system of PDEs with an ill-conditioned matrix.
I have the system of non-homogeneous First Order One-Way Wave Equations
$$\frac{\partial {\bf \overrightarrow u}}{\partial t}+{\bf \underline A}\frac{\partial {\bf \overrightarrow u}}{\partial x}={\bf\overrightarrow b}$$
where ${\bf \underline A} \in \mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3$ is non-sparse and rather ill-conditioned such that the elements of ${\bf \underline A}$ along with the vector ${\bf\overrightarrow b\in \mathbb{R}^3}$ are as indicated below in order of magnitude

The elements of the vector $\bf \overrightarrow u\in \mathbb{R}^3$ are all of order 1. What I have noticed is that owing to the large condition number of the matrix, explicit methods (Explicit Euler, Lax-Friedrichs, Lax Wendroff) all fail. Pivoting (swapping Rows 1 and 2) does not help.
The upstream implicit method though, does converge nicely, although it is only First Order accurate in both space and time.
For the scalar versions of the first order wave equation, there are higher order implicit methods that employ a tri-diagonal matrix algorithm - the size of the matrix being the number $N$ of grid locations. In the scalar case, this implementation is straightforward. The extension of this approach to the vector form entails a large number of matrix inversions and multiplications as each element of the tri-diagonal matrix of order $N$  is itself a 3$\times$ 3 matrix. While I'm currently implementing this, It is also not entirely clear to me that given the condition of the matrix, this approach would be efficient.
Any suggestions for how I can get an explicit scheme (or ANY other scheme for that matter!) to work for the above system would be deeply appreciated.

Doesn‘t the first Order implicit method yield sufficient results? Ususally it already gives very accurate results

If the eigenvalues Are as large as you say, explicit methods Are destined to fail

Without comparing the results of a First Order method to a Second Order one, I'll have to assume that it is as you say sufficiently accurate. The eigenvalue is actually of $O(1)$, but I suspect that it's the large $O(10^6$ term that is causing havoc with the explicit system - the errors propagate in space rapidly., even with the timestep limited by the CFL criterion.

CFL is only necessary, not sufficient for stability. You might want to try to simulate with a characteristic function of a square as initial datum to check for diffusion, which would give you an idea of how precise it is. How large are the eigenvalues of $A$?

Agreed. I think the insufficiency is in stark evidence here. The characteristic equation is practically linear and for the case I'm simulating, the eigenvalue is 4.94. What's weird is that according to Descartes' Rule of Signs there should be two positive roots, and if they are both positive and coincident, the other root must also be real and negative. I just don't see that negative root from the characfteristic equation.

I haven't seen the characteristic equation

The characteristic equation is $-\lambda^3 + 15.08 \lambda^2+1.633\times 10^8 \lambda -8.07\times 10^8=0$

According to WolframAlpha, there is a large root at around $12784$ and a very small one around $-12773$

So your time stepsize will be extremely small in an explicit scheme

AHA! That would explain it! The spatial step divided by 12784 gives me a small enough time step at which the Lax-Friedrichs method does indeed work - even if impractical! Thanks for digging into this!

@HyperbolicPDEfriend something really strange that I've noticed is that the upstream implicit method breaks down for smaller time steps, but is very stable at much larger time steps. Looking at the algorithm as $\delta t$ shrinks to zero, the solution should remain at the initial condition. Is there an explanation for this behaviour?! Thanks

I meant $\Delta t$

Sorry, I am not an expert on implicit methods… But generally, one should always choose the time stepsize as large as possible, because loss of Information is usually minimal
